# For Loop over a function with a for loop inside

Tags: python, function, for-loop, matplotlib

So I am trying to perform a for loop over the subplots, in order to correctly label the bars in each subplot individually. I know that I should make a loop over the 'autolabel' function, but I just can't seem to make it work. In the examples, it looks like the values are picking the right spot inside the graph, but aren't picking the correct plot to be displayed in.

This is my code to visualize, after prepping the data.

```
# 4. visualise
# plot style
plt.style.use('ggplot')
# create subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, sharey=True, figsize=[16,5])

# create bar containers for plots
opleiding_plot = ax[0].bar(opleidingsniveau.index, opleidingsniveau)
geslacht_plot = ax[1].bar(geslacht.index, geslacht)
coachervaring_plot = ax[2].bar(coachervaring.index, coachervaring['Coachervaring'])
sport_plot = ax[3].bar(sport.index, sport)



# create function to add frequency above all bars
plots = [0,1,2,3]

for i in plots:
    def autolabel(bars):
        # attach some text labels
        for bar in bars:
            height = bar.get_height()
            ax[i].text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2., 1.02*height,
                    '%d' % int(height),
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
        
# use function over bar containers
autolabel(opleiding_plot)
autolabel(geslacht_plot)
autolabel(coachervaring_plot)
autolabel(sport_plot)

ax[0].title.set_text('Opleidingsniveau')
ax[0].set_xticklabels(['HBO', 'VO & MBO', 'WO en Post-WO'],rotation=20)
ax[1].title.set_text('Geslacht')
ax[2].title.set_text('Coachervaring in jaren')
ax[2].set_xticks([0,1,2,3])
ax[2].set_xticklabels(['0 t/m 6', '7 t/m 9', '10 t/m 16', '17 en hoger'], rotation=20)
ax[3].title.set_text('Sport')

plt.ylim([0,50])
plt.ylabel('Aantallen')
plt.show()
```

And this was the result. It seems the labels aren't labelled correctly.
[image]

I have also tried this with the for loop over plots in a different spot.

```
def autolabel(bars):
    # attach some text labels
    for bar in bars:
        height = bar.get_height()
        for i in plots:
            ax[i].text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2., 1.02*height,
                    '%d' % int(height),
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image]

Btw I also tried to write:

```
plots = [0]
for i in enumerate(plots):
    def autolabel(bars):
        # attach some text labels
        for bar in bars:
            height = bar.get_height()
            ax[i].text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2., 1.02*height,
                    '%d' % int(height),
                    ha='center', va='bottom')
```

which gave me this error:
IndexError: too many indices for array

I've lost hope a little for today haha. Hopefully someone can help me out with this problem.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a step back and try labelling the first ax correctly before trying to iterate on the others.

Comment: Also, define your function outside of any loop and mind the fact that enumerate() returns both an index and a value from 'plots' variable (which are the same here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no data, I diverted the sample data from Seabon. The modifications to the function are to make the graph unit the outer loop and the bar graph the inner loop, and to use the enumerate function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

p1 = tips.groupby('sex')['total_bill'].sum().to_frame()
p2 = tips.groupby('smoker')['total_bill'].sum().to_frame()
p3 = tips.groupby('day')['total_bill'].sum().to_frame()
p4 = tips.groupby('time')['total_bill'].sum().to_frame()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,4, sharey=True, figsize=[16,5])

opleiding_plot = ax[0].bar(p1.index, p1.total_bill)
geslacht_plot = ax[1].bar(p2.index, p2.total_bill)
coachervaring_plot = ax[2].bar(p3.index, p3.total_bill)
sport_plot = ax[3].bar(p4.index, p4.total_bill)

plot_list = [opleiding_plot,geslacht_plot,coachervaring_plot,sport_plot]

def autolabel(plots):
    for i,bars in enumerate(plots):
        for k,b in enumerate(bars):
            height = b.get_height()
            # print(height)
            ax[i].text(b.get_x() + b.get_width()/2., 1.02*height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(plot_list)

ax[0].title.set_text('Opleidingsniveau')
ax[0].set_xticklabels(['HBO', 'VO & MBO', 'WO en Post-WO'],rotation=20)
ax[1].title.set_text('Geslacht')
ax[2].title.set_text('Coachervaring in jaren')
ax[2].set_xticks([0,1,2,3])
ax[2].set_xticklabels(['0 t/m 6', '7 t/m 9', '10 t/m 16', '17 en hoger'], rotation=20)
ax[3].title.set_text('Sport')

# plt.ylim([0,50])
plt.ylabel('Aantallen')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked, thanks! In the past I used to share my data with dput() for R. What's the way to do that for Python?
"The modifications to the function are to make the graph unit the outer loop and the bar graph the inner loop, and to use the enumerate function." Great explanation, this helps me understand it :) I still find it hard to breakdown sometimes, homeschooled :)